# If the same string literal appears in code twice, does it appear in the executable once?

Tags: rust

Let's say that I created some Rust source code that combines lots of duplicate string literals. Are they de-duplicated during the compilation process?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! If you create the following program, which prints the memory address of two variables, you'll see that they print the same value. That is, both `a` and `b` refer to the same underlying data.

```
fn main() {
    let a = "Hello";
    let b = "Hello";
    
    println!("{:p} {:p}", a, b);
}
```

To try this out yourself, you can [run the program within the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=634ffbbaf00560b8b958e6e84c6361ff). Here's one example output:

```
0x55b17e61905b 0x55b17e61905b
```

It's possible to take this idea even further. Let's experiment by scattering the same literal in different functions and modules.

```
static GREETING: &'static str = "Hello";

#[inline(never)]
fn f1() {
    let f1_greeting = "Hello";
    println!("{:p}", f1_greeting);
}

#[inline(never)]
fn f2() {
    let f2_greeting = "Hello";
    println!("{:p}", f2_greeting);
}

mod submodule {
    pub fn f3() {
        let f3_greeting = "Hello";
        println!("{:p}", f3_greeting);   
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = "Hello";
    let b = "Hello";
    
    println!("{:p}", GREETING);
    println!("{:p}", a);
    println!("{:p}", b);
    f1();
    f2();
    submodule::f3();
}
```

You'll see that [the outcome is the same](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f14ced8bc0feeed8afbca9e7b88a2e96): only one copy of the literal is loaded into memory.

```
0x55b17e61905b
0x55b17e61905b
0x55b17e61905b
0x55b17e61905b
0x55b17e61905b
0x55b17e61905b
```

Comment: Does this hold when the strings are in different functions? Different modules? Different crates?

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as John points out. Would you mind to add more examples, showing the different cases, please?

Comment: Thanks for checking different modules. What about different crates? I'm curious if the optimization works across crate boundaries since crates are compiled separately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Tim McNamara gave a good and concise way of confirming this, but if you want to explore further to see how this works, you can also try getting the assembly code output from Rust (you can try this on [Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/d4soPh139)):

```rust
pub fn test() -> (&'static str, &'static str) {
    let a = "Hello";
    let b = "Hello";

    (a, b)
}
```

Use `rustc` to get assembly output (`--crate-type=lib` ensures that unused functions are not cleaned up as "dead code"):

```
rustc src/main.rs -o output.s --emit asm --crate-type=lib
```

And in the assembly output, you should see something like this (the output can differ based on a number of factors):

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 11, 0
    .globl  __ZN4main4test17h1a94a89cb89e6ba1E
    .p2align    2
__ZN4main4test17h1a94a89cb89e6ba1E:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov x9, x8
    adrp    x10, l___unnamed_1@PAGE
    add x10, x10, l___unnamed_1@PAGEOFF
    mov x8, x10
    str x8, [x9]
    mov w8, #5
    str x8, [x9, #8]
    str x10, [x9, #16]
    str x8, [x9, #24]
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __TEXT,__const
l___unnamed_1:
    .ascii  "Hello"

.subsections_via_symbols
```

There is a single label `l___unnamed_1` which contains the string literal `Hello` and it is used twice.